# Sorting an integer without using string methods and without using arrays

Tags: javascript, math

can anyone come with an idea of how to sort an integer without using an array, and without using string methods as well as `sort()` method?
for example

input: `642531`
output: `123456`

I started by writing 2 simple functions - one which checks the length of the number, the other one splits the integer at some point and switches between 2 desired numbers. Below are the 2 functions.

I got stuck with the rest of the solution...

```js
function switchDigits(num, i) { // for input: num=642531, i = 4 returns 624135
  let temp = num;
  let rest = 0;

  for (let j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
    rest = rest * 10;
    rest = rest + temp % 10;
    temp = (temp - temp % 10) / 10;
  }

  let a = temp % 10;
  temp = (temp - a) / 10;
  let b = temp % 10;
  temp = (temp - b) / 10;
  temp = Math.pow(10, i - 2) * temp;
  temp = temp + 10 * a + b;
  temp = Math.pow(10, i - 1) * temp;
  temp = temp + rest;

  return temp;
}

function checkHowManyDigits(num) { //input: 642534, output: 6 (length of the integer)
  let count = 0;

  while (num > 0) {
    let a = num % 10;
    num = (num - a) / 10;
    count++;
  }

  return count;
}

let num = 642534;
let i = checkHowManyDigits(num);
console.log(switchDigits(num));
```

Comment: why dont you just `Number(72987239.toString().split("").sort((a,b) => a - b).join(""))`

Comment: @Ifaruki Because of the first sentence in the question: _"...without using string methods as well as sort() method..."_

Comment: What is the point here. Why you don't want to use `sort` or `string` methods?

Comment: well, it's a question from a test I had yesterday

Comment: Question mentions without using sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually complicated requirement and so does this answer. It's pure logic and as it is `it's a question from a test` you should try understanding the logic on your own as a homework.

```js
function checkHowManyDigits(num) { //input: 642534, output: 6 (length of the integer)
  let count = 0;

  while (num > 0) {
    let a = num % 10;
    num = (num - a) / 10;
    count++;
  }

  return count;
}

function sortDigit(numOriginal) {

  let i = checkHowManyDigits(numOriginal);
  let minCount = 0;
  let min = 10;
  let num = numOriginal;

  while (num > 0) {
    let d = num % 10;
    num = (num - d) / 10;
    if (d < min) {
      min = d;
      minCount = 0;
    } else if (d === min) {
      minCount++;
    }
  }

  let result = 0;
  while (minCount >= 0) {
    result += min * Math.pow(10, i - minCount - 1);
    minCount--;
  }

  let newNum = 0;
  num = numOriginal;
  while (num > 0) {
    let d = num % 10;        
    num = (num - d) / 10;
    if (d !== min) {
      newNum = newNum * 10 + d;
    }
  }
  
  if (newNum == 0) return result;
  else return result += sortDigit(newNum);

}

console.log(sortDigit(642531));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I indeed spent many efforts and time, as well as consulting with friends of mine, all after the test was over and a day after. Turned here after I was sure this was a rediculous question to my level

Comment: Sorry, new here hehe... Did I do it right? Accepting the answer is by checking the V?

Comment: or you can upvote and accept the other answer ... scnr ...

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look to greater and smaller pairs, like

```
64
46
```

The delta is `18`, which gets an idea if you compare other pairs, like

```
71
17
```

where the delta is `54`. Basically any difference of two digits is a multiple of `9`.

This in mind, you get a function for taking a single digit out of a number and a single loop who is sorting the digits by using the calculated delta and subtract the value, adjusted by the place.

```js
function sort(number) {
    const
        getDigit = e => Math.floor(number / 10 ** e) % 10,
        l = Math.ceil(Math.log10(number)) - 1;

    let e = l;

    while (e--) {
        const
            left = getDigit(e + 1),
            right = getDigit(e);

        if (left <= right) continue;
        number += (right - left) * 9 * 10 ** e;
        e = l;
    }

    return number;
}


console.log(sort(17)); // 17
console.log(sort(71)); // 17
console.log(sort(642531)); // 123456
console.log(sort(987123654)); // 123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I found the best solution.

*This solution is based on a Java solution I found in StackOverFlow forums.

```
let store = 0;

function getReducedNumbr(number, digit) {

    console.log("Remove " + digit + " from " + number);

    let newNumber = 0;
    let repeateFlag = false;

    while (number>0) {
        let t = number % 10;
        if (t !== digit) {
            newNumber = (newNumber * 10) + t;
        } else if (t == digit) {
            if (repeateFlag) {
                console.log(("Repeated min digit " + t + " found. Store is : " + store));
                store = (store * 10) + t;
                console.log("Repeated min digit " + t + " added to store. Updated store is : " + store);
                
            } else {
                repeateFlag = true;
            }
        }
        number = Math.floor(number / 10);
    }
    console.log("Reduced number is : " + newNumber);
    return newNumber;}


function sortNum(num) {
    let number = num;
    let original = number;
    let digit;

    while (number > 0) {
        digit = number % 10;
        console.log("Last digit is : " + digit + " of number : " + number);
        temp = Math.floor(number/10);

        while (temp > 0) {
            console.log("subchunk is " + temp);
            t = temp % 10;

            if (t < digit) {
                digit = t;
            }

            temp = Math.floor(temp/10);
            
        }
        console.log("Smallest digit in " + number + " is " + digit);

        store = (store * 10) + digit;
        console.log("store is : " + store);

        number = getReducedNumbr(number, digit);
        
        
    }
    console.log(("Ascending order of " + original + " is " + store));
    return store;
    
}

console.log(sortNum(4214173));
```

you can see how it works here https://jsfiddle.net/9dpm14fL/1/